# passing 'val' type to a function

Tags: function, scala

I was working on a code in which I declared a 'val' type variable and passed it to a recursive function which changes it:

```
def calculateDates(from: LocalDate, until: LocalDate, by: RDate, holidays: HolidayCalendar): Seq[LocalDate] = 
{
    val dateSeq: Seq[LocalDate] = Seq(from)
    def calculateDatesRecur(from: LocalDate, dateSeq: Seq[LocalDate]): Seq[LocalDate] =
   {
        val date = by(from, holidays)
        if (date.compareTo(until) <= 0)
          calculateDatesRecur(date, dateSeq :+ date)
        else
          dateSeq
   }
   calculateDatesRecur(from, dateSeq)
}
```

'dateSeq' is a variable that ultimately is a list of dates from 'from' to 'until'. Well, it turns out it works. It shouldn't right? Because the 'dateSeq' variable has been initialised as 'val'. Is it that a copy of it is sent to the recursive function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't that a copy of `dateSeq` is passed into `calculateDatesRecur`, rather, the expression `dateSeq :+ date` creates a new `Seq[Date]` (with the newly added date, and without modifying the `dateSeq` parameter), which is then passed to the recursive call. In this way, a final `Seq[Date]` is built up from successive immutable, intermediate values, and eventually handed back when the `else` clause is executed.

Answer (score 0):

`dateSeq :+ date` returns the new object. Check the definition of :+ method: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq